# How to Select only not empty fields from Db

Tags: sql-server, json

I´m writing an application that relies on Ajax requests to retrieve data from a dataBase, the required info is delivered in a Json set of objects, this means that even for the empty fields of the dataBase a pair of propriety/value is generated:

```
[{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":""},{"field1":"","field2":"","field3":""}]
```

How can I Select only not empty fields from the dataBase via SQL avoiding generating and sending unnecessary data?

Comment: How about if say, for field1, row1 not empty but row2 is empty?

Comment: then the object for the first row carries a pair for field1 and the second doesn't. but has  Matt Whitfield points maybe it´s a question of serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data in the table is NULL then you can selected records as appropriate using something like

```
SELECT [fieldList]
  FROM [tableName]
 WHERE [field_1] IS NOT NULL
    OR [field_2] IS NOT NULL
    OR [field_3] IS NOT NULL
```

However - if you want to omit the definitions from the JSON for partially empty records, such that

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":""}
```

was transmitted as

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
```

Then that is something you would need to do by customising whatever JSON Serializer you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE LEN(valuefield) > 0
```